# How to make a DataFrame visible in Python cell in Databricks notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I created Spark DataFrame in Scala using Databricks. After doing some preprocessing,I came up with a smaller data subset that fits into memory. Therefore I want to convert it to Pandas and then save as CSV file.

The problem is that the DataFrame `df` on which I worked in Databricks notebook in Scala cells is not visible in a Python cell.

%python

```
df.toPandas().to_csv("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/test.csv", header=True, index=False)
```

How can I make `df` visible in the Python cell?

Comment: Probably too good to be true, but: `df_py = df.toPandas().to_csv("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/test.csv", header=True, index=False)` And then `print(df_py)`?

Comment: @Erfan: It does not work. It says that `df` cannot be found: `NameError: name 'df' is not defined`. But `df` exists in the above cell that I executed successfully before.

Comment: You don't need to export to csv actually, just do: `df_py = df.toPandas()` Then `print(df_py)`

Comment: @Erfan: This should be Python cell, right? If so, the thing is that `df` is not visible in Python cell.

Comment: Try it in Spark cell, after that use `df_py` in python cell

Comment: @Erfan: It will not work in Spark cell, because I use Scala by default, not PySpark.

Answer (score 2):

Do this `display(df)` . It usually displays some nested Structs as well.

Or I would do something like this 
`df.createOrReplaceTempView("dfViewName")`
In the next cell 
`%sql`

`Select * from dfViewName`

Comment: `display(df)` is exactly what I need. Regarding sql, I think that it would be useful if I wanted to use SQL in the next cell, but I wanted to use Python. Since my final goal was just to save CSV file, display is the right solution.

Comment: By the way, which approach would I use to save DataFrame to make it accessible in another Databricks Notebook on the same cluster?

Comment: @Erfan: I wanted pandas for saving the DataFrame as CSV file. Sorry, if it was unclear. Of course, I apprecate to see a solution with Pandas. But if it's impossible, then "display" would be a workaround for me.